# php not receives data from ajax FormData

Tags: php, ajax, apache, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm trying to send multiple data and files by jquery ajax (using formData) to a php file but i don't recive anything in the php file neither $_POST nor $_FILE data, I receive NULL in both.

Here is my ajax function.

```
$('#formulario').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:"../phpfile.php",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"JSON",
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).always(function(respuesta){
        //code
    });
});
```

Here is my HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                        <div class='row'>
                            <div class='col-xs-12'>
                                <h4>Destinatarios</h4>
                                <select class='form-control' required name='destinatarios[]' title='Selecciona cuantos quieras' multiple data-selected-text-format="count>2" data-live-search="true">
                                    {%for familiar in familia%}
                                        <option value='{{familiar.ID_PERSONA}}'>{{familiar.NOMBRE}} {{familiar.APELLIDOS}}</option>
                                    {%endfor%}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-xs-6 hidden'>
                                <h4>Tipo de entrega</h4>
                                <select class='form-control' id='entrega' name='entrega'>
                                        <option value='1' selected></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class='col-xs-4 text-center'>
                                                <h4>Despues de mi partida</h4>
                                                <input type="radio" value="muerte" name="tipoE" onchange="cambioR(this)">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='col-xs-4 text-center'>
                                                <h4>En fecha determinada</h4>
                                                <input type="radio" value="fecha" name="tipoE" onchange="cambioR(this)">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='col-xs-4 text-center'>
                                                <h4>En mi ceremonia de despedida</h4>
                                                <input type="radio" value="ceremonia" name="tipoE" onchange="cambioR(this)">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div id="f" class="hidden">
                                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                    <div class="input-group date" id="sandbox-container">
                                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Fecha</span>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="fecha" id="fecha">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <br>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="m" class="hidden">
                                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Días después de mi partida</span>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="muerte" name="muerte">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <br>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <h4>Mensaje</h4>
                                <input class="hidden" id="nombre_mensaje" name="nombre_mensaje">
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" style="resize: none" id='mensaje' name='mensaje' required></textarea>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <h4>Imágenes / Video / Audio / Archivos</h4>
                                <div class="grid" id="muestras" dc>
                                    <div class="grid-item col-xs-3 deseo" onclick="novoFile(this);">
                                        <img src="../Recursos/imagenes/plus.jpg" width="100%;">
                                        <input class="hidden" type="file" onchange="cambio(this);" name="files[]">
                                        <input class="hidden datas" name="data_multimedia[]" value="0">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input class="hidden" id="id_mensaje" name="id_mensaje">
                        <input type="reset" id="reiniciar" hidden>
                    </form>
```

The user can upload as many files as he want, and the html input file is added dinamicly using jquery.

Comment: Reduce your problem to a test case, minimal example with the problem. It will be better to get an answer and you might even resolve it by yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
new FormData(this);
```

with:

```
$('#formulario').serialize();
```

Comment: that won't help with file uploads. you MUST use `FormData` for ajax uploads.